# How to correctly receive data via socketDataArrived method on client side

Tags: sockets, tcp, omnet++, packet, inet

I have created in my simulation in omnet++ Server node and client node. Client successfully sends my custom message to the server. The server received this message and send back response message successfully also.

The client receives a message via socketDataArrived() method, but when I try to cast this message from incoming cPacket type to my custom message type, segmentation fault error occurs:

`Thread 1 "opp_run_dbg" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff586c394 in __dynamic_cast () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

This is my code to cast message:

```
void TCPClientApp::socketDataArrived(int connId, void * yourPtr, cPacket * msg, bool urgent){
    auto message = dynamic_cast<cMessage*>(msg);
    if(message){
        auto appmsg = dynamic_cast<GenericAppMsg*>(message);
        ....
}
```

The problem occurs on the line with code `auto appmsg = dynamic_cast<GenericAppMsg*>(message);`

Have you any idea why this happens and how to correctly process received data?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of INET do you use? Try to set `debug-on-errors = true` in `omnetpp.ini` and then debug you project - the debugger will stop just in line that causes an error.

Comment: I am using INET  3.6.4 because of I am using artery - https://github.com/riebl/artery/tree/master/extern . I have debug setup to on and line that causes an error is as I described in quescion ... I also added before this line (auto appmsg = dynamic...) this one `auto name = message->getName();` and same Segmentation fault error occurs there. It seems like there is some problem with cPacket* msg which I received.

Comment: The line `auto message = dynamic_cast<cMessage*>(msg);` is unnecessary (every `cPacket` is `cMessage`), so I suggest removing it. I have looked at your other question in SO and I suppose that you manipulate `kind` of message by hand and it may cause this errors. `kind` is used by TCPSocket for internal purpose and one cannot set `kind` manually. You have the whole payload of TCP packet and you can prepare and use own message format, own fields etc.

Comment: @JerzyD. Ok then, I created my server app like TCPGenericSrvApp.cc from INET. In `handleMessage()` function, I received an incoming message from the client. Then I create and send response message like -> 
`auto packet = new GenericAppMsg("Response");
     packet->setControlInfo(cmd);
            packet->setByteLength(300);
            packet->setKind(TCP_C_SEND);
     packet->encapsulate(myAnotherCustomMsg);
            sendOrSchedule(packet, delay);` When I delete setter for kind, this error occurs - [link](https://i.imgur.com/l2J8qem.png) Can you help?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code of sending the packet as well as the code of receiving it?